# How do I dynamically build an array in a JS object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapquest

The following code works fine:

```
direction.route(
{
     start: '30 Baker St, Old City, YY 12345',
     end: '30 Bogus Address Ave, Fake, ZZ 12345',
     waypoints: [ "<address1>", "<address2>" ] //Array using literals
     
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I may have dozens of addresses stored in an array.  The number of addresses in the array will vary.

The following code would work, but I need to be able to build the array within th JS object dynamically.

```
direction.route(
{
     start: '30 Baker St, Old City, YY 12345',
     end: '30 Bogus Address Ave, Fake, ZZ 12345',
     waypoints: [ address[0], address[1], address[2], ... ] //Array using variables
     
});
```

Comment: Try using spread syntax, `waypoints: [ ...address ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: You can't pass the array as is? `waypoints: address`

Comment: @GuyIncognito There are important caveats with that -- changes made to `waypoints` would affect `address`, for instance.

Comment: So @HereticMonkey is right! The result will be like: `waypoints: address.slice()`

Comment: You don't say. That's why I asked, if the OP doesn't pass the original array because they actually need a copy, or do they just not know that the original array can be used. Cloning a large array if the function doesn't modify it would just waste memory.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl:  That worked like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: @GuyIncognito Well, the OP, doesn't appear to know much about the issue in general, so I thought the warning would be good to have to forestall further duplicate questions later on about why `address` changes when they change `waypoints`...

Comment: @GuyIncognito  your  `waypoints: address` also worked.  However,  I'm following your exchange with @HereticMonkey.  I've got loads to learn here.  Thanks

Comment: @HereticMonkey the link you gave me worked as well.
`waypoints: address.slice()`

Comment: @ezG It should provide you with the opportunity to acknowledge that the linked question's answers answered your question as well. A button or something? It's been a while since I've gotten a look at the UX. If you click it, it will close this question, leaving it available as a signpost for others to find if they search for a question similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it using the MapQuest sample addresses.

```
var address = [];
address.push('366 Columbus Ave, New York, NY 10024');
address.push('881 7th Ave, New York, NY 10019');

L.mapquest.directions().route({
  start: '350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118',
  end: 'One Liberty Plaza, New York, NY 10006',
  waypoints: address OR waypoints: [address[0], address[1]]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I settled on

```
     var direction = L.mapquest.directions();
 direction.route(
 {
      start: '30 Baker St, Old City, YY 12345',
      end: '30 Bogus Address Ave, Fake, ZZ 12345',
      waypoints: locations2.slice(), //NOTE:  "Spread syntax" worked just as well here too.
      optimizeWaypoints: true
 });
```

Acknowledgments to the following for GIVING me the answer:
Heretic-Monkey, Mr. PolyWhirl, and Guy Incognito